# Generating permutations of a 10-element vector with 8 zeros and 2 ones in R

Tags: r, permutation

I'm generating 10-element vectors of 0s and 1s and varying the possible number of 1s from 2 to 9.

For example
2 values = 1

```
1000000010
```

3 values = 1

```
1010100000
```

**EDIT: I want to efficiently generate all possible combinations.**

I have a crude way of doing this but I'm guessing there is a simpler way to achieve this using some sort of permutation function.

My way:
Using the `sample` function in R:  I start with a vector of all zeros and draw 2 random numbers from 1 to 10 without replacement and uses those as indices of elements in the vector to change to 1.  I do this a lot of times then toss our the duplicates.

```
mat <- matrix(data = 0,nrow = 1000,ncol = 10) #matrix to hold output
vect <- rep(NA, 1000) 
v0 <- rep(0,10)                              #initial vector of all 0s
for(i in 1:dim(mat)[1]){
  mat[i, sample(1:10, 2)] <- 1

  vect[i] <- paste(mat[i,], collapse = "")   #collapse vector to a string
}

mat[duplicated(vect) !=T,]                       #remove duplicates
```

This is a round about way to do it but gets the job done.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: What's your intention: generating _randomly_ a number of vectors of 0 and 1 or do you want to create _all_ possible combinations of 0/1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate all permutations with 2 ones in a 10 element vector, use `combn(10,2)` to enumerate all possible position:

```
t(apply(combn(10,2),2,function(x){ tmp<-rep(0,10); tmp[x]<-1; return(tmp) }))
```

This returns 45 different permutations same result as the OP's code using sampling but more efficient.

Comment: Similarly, you could use `t(combn(10, 2, function(x) tabulate(x, 10)))`